# Sorting Python dictionary by value; value is a two-item list; regular sort on first list item, reverse sort on second item

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose values are all two-item lists (the key is a six-item tuple, but we won't get into that).

Here's a visualization:

```
my_ridiculous_dict = {
    ('0', '2', '0', '4', '0', '1'): [1, 1000], 
    ('5', '3', '0', '2', '0', '0'): [1, 400], 
    ('3', '6', '0', '2', '0', '0'): [2, 3000], 
    ('4', '3', '0', '2', '0', '0'): [2, 80], 
    ('0', '0', '3', '9', '0', '3'): [3, 0]
}
```

I need to sort it first by the first item in the value's list, then with a reverse sort on the second item.  So what you see above would be sorted correctly

Apologies if this has been addressed, but all the questions I've seen on sorting dictionaries by value seem to assume a simple int or str as the value, & I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the use of lambdas or itemgetters given this added complexity.

Should mention I don't mind doing this in two sort passes, just would like to git'r'done!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot really sort a dictionary, please, provide the output you expect?

Comment: problem's been solved, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries aren't meant to be sorted but if you copy the items to a list, you can sort the list.

```
mrd = {
('4', '3', '0', '2', '0', '0'): [2, 80], 
('0', '2', '0', '4', '0', '1'): [1, 1000], 
('3', '6', '0', '2', '0', '0'): [2, 3000], 
('5', '3', '0', '2', '0', '0'): [1, 400], 
('0', '0', '3', '9', '0', '3'): [3, 0]
}

lst = list(mrd)
lst.sort(key=lambda x:[mrd[x][0], -mrd[x][1]])
for i in lst: print(i, mrd[i])
```

Output:

```
('0', '2', '0', '4', '0', '1') [1, 1000]
('5', '3', '0', '2', '0', '0') [1, 400]
('3', '6', '0', '2', '0', '0') [2, 3000]
('4', '3', '0', '2', '0', '0') [2, 80]
('0', '0', '3', '9', '0', '3') [3, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Python uses a stable sort

A more general solution relies on the fact that the sorts are stable in Python.  That means that if two items sort the same, then they retain their original order.

To get what you want, do a reversed sort by the second value. Use `my_dict.items()` to get (key, value) tuples.  `t[1][1]` is the second value.

```
items = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda t:t[1][1], reverse=True)
```

Then sort by the first value.

```
items.sort(key=lambda t:t[1][0])
```

In current versions of Python, dicts maintain items in key-insertion-order.  So you could create a sorted dict by:

```
my_sorted_dict = dict(items)
```

#### using operator.itemgetter()

I don't see a way to use itemgetter on a nested data structure, such as the (key, [value1, value2]) that my_dict.items() provides.  So, to use `operator.itemgetter()` the structure would need to be flattened.

```
import operator

items = [(k, *v) for k,v in my_dict.items()]
```

This turns it into a tuple of elements like: (k, value1, value2).

Now sort the list like before; second element, then first element.  `operator.itemgetter(n)` creates and returns a function that takes an object and calls `__getitem__(n)` on that object.  Thus, these lines do a reverse sort keyed by item[2] for each item in items, then a sort keyed by item[1].

```
items.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
items.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Then a dict comprehension builds the sorted dict:

```
my_sorted_dict = {k:[v1,v2] for k,v1,v2 in items}
```

my_sorted_dict

Comment: Brilliant!  I got almost this far but I was concentrating on itemgetters due to purported performance advantages.

Comment: If anyone knows a way to do this via the itemgetters methodology, I'd love to hear it still

Comment: Added itemgetters() above.